# Jquery load php file into div doesnt seem to work

Tags: php, jquery

So i got this script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#feedback").load('check.php');
});
```

And i would like to load the check.php file. Into the div with the id feedback. It wont work. Do i miss something?

Comment: Is that the entirety of your JavaScript/jQuery code?

Comment: What happens instead? Do you get any error messages in the debug console of your browser? Is the check.php file requested (check your server logs)?

Comment: yes that what my .js file contains, that is included in the same site where my div is.

Comment: nothing happens it just wont appear. It should say "Hello".

Comment: Take your code out of the .js file and place it between the `head` tags of your page using `<script type="text/javascript">[code]</script>`.

Comment: This code looks good, can you confirm the file exists and has an output. (You won't see anything if the file had no echo).

Comment: the file exists, it has an echo. and its in the same folder as the .js file

Comment: this should be check against the db if the username already exists, but i cant even autoload the file.

Comment: you should `echo` something otherwise its better to `include` it.

Comment: what error are you getting?. . . What does check.php contain?. . Is it empty? . . .

Comment: @Toma: What is the path for current php file and 'check.php' ?

Comment: `<?php   echo 'HELLO'; ?>` this is in the check.php file. It is in a different folder then the php file with the div is.

Comment: Have you inserted jquery script before using $() . .  ?

Comment: too few information, the solution is trial/error.

Comment: What foldr ? Mention the folder paths? Or place both your main page and check.php in same folder

Comment: yes jq is insterted, i use other scripts, for example checking if retyped password is correct and it is working.

Answer (score 1):

'check.php' must be in same directory where your current php file is stored. If you can't change location of the file. Change path in your code like

```
$("#feedback").load('../path/to/folder/check.php');
```

Comment: doesnt matter for now where the file is. So i put it in the same folder as where i want to icnlude it. Still wont show.

Comment: Can you tell URLs for both files ? Write URL of check.php in browser address bar and see what 's displaying on page.

Comment: this is the url where i want to see my check.php file. http://localhost/firstapp/index.php/tblUsers/create the chehc.php is in the same file as the create.php

Comment: Are you using `Codeigniter` or any other `framework`?

Answer (score 0):

is index.php in your quetion "localhost/firstapp/**index.php**/tblUsers/create" folder or file?

Comment: its a file, the entrance to the framework. The tblIsers is a folder where the user actions take place like create, list.. etc.

Comment: hmm, when index.php is a file, you cat'n open this as folder (index.php/...).